# Unable to get the response body on client for POST call from node express server

Tags: node.js, express, post, https, httpresponse

I have a client that makes a Post call to my express server hosted on heroku.

When I make a simple POST call, I do not see any response on my client. I am however seeing the correct response on the network, I just am unable to get it where I want it, ie my client js.

The client:

```
               fetch('/getLongToken', {
                method:'post',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type':'text/plain'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(orgReqBody)
            }).then(resp => {
                    if(resp == 'NO_LONG_TOKEN'){
                        console.log('no long token ');
                    } else if (resp.body == 'NO_TOKEN'){
                        console.log('NO TOKEN');
                    }
            }).catch(err => {
                    console.log(`the logged error is ${err}`);
            })
```

The express route :

```
    app.post('/getLongToken/', (req, res)=> {
      let orgId = orgToTokenMap.get(JSON.parse(req).orgId);
      if(orgId == undefined){
        res.send({msg:"NO_LONG_TOKEN"});
      } else {
          //some other processing//
      }
})
```

No matter what I tried, with even a simple

```
res.send('TEST');
```

I am unable to get any response in my client. Even tried text, json with no luck.

I suspected a cors issue and even tried setting cors and headers but to no effect.

I must be doing something very elemental wrong. Can you please help me figure out what I am missing?

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Have you tried to `return res.send(...)` ?

Comment: Hi @Skaleb, I tried this now, no luck. The thing is, I can see the response in the network traffic, but no in my client which is just a simple page on the browser. However, I can see the response for a GET call no problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the issue with my code.

I was using fetch API to make the POST call and it does not return a ready to use response object.

I changed my code from

```
fetch('/getLongToken', {
            method:'post',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type':'text/plain'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(orgReqBody)
        }).then(resp => {
                if(resp == 'NO_LONG_TOKEN'){
                    console.log('no long token ');
                } else if (resp.body == 'NO_TOKEN'){
                    console.log('NO TOKEN');
                }
        }).catch(err => {
                console.log(`the logged error is ${err}`);
        })
```

To :

```
fetch('/getLongToken', {
                method:'post',
                headers: {
                    //'Content-Type':'text/plain'
                    'Content-Type':'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(orgReqBody)
            }).then(resp => {
                    resp = resp.json().then(respJson => {
                        console.log(`the json resp is logged as ${JSON.stringify(respJson)}`);
                        if(respJson.msg === 'NO_LONG_TOKEN'){
                            console.log('no long token ');
```

and it worked.

So I had to convert my fetch response to json again via the .json on the first promise's then block.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending an object as a response, so you must check that object on the client. You must also know how is the response structure according to the library you are using (i. e. Axios or native request). Assuming your response object is on `resp` you may:

```js
if (resp.msg === 'NO_LONG_TOKEN') {
  console.log('no long token ');
} else if (resp.msg === 'NO_TOKEN') {
 console.log('NO TOKEN');
}
```